# Excel Solver - Optimizing Using Changing "ValueOf" Inputs

Tags: excel

I'm trying to set up a macro that can parameterize an equation given 2 inputs. I cannot figure out a way to have Solver use the value of a cell as the "Value Of" though. The macro I've got at the moment is as follows:

```
Sub Macro2()

   SolverReset
   SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$2", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="100"
   SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$2", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
   SolverOk SetCell:="$M$6", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:="$B$2", ByChange:="$G$2", Engine:= _
       3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"
   SolverSolve

End Sub
```

When the macro is executed, the Solver Results box pops up saying `Error in model. Please verify that all cells and Constraints are valid.`

Is there any way to accomplish what I'd like to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nat.

Instead of directly referencing a cell for the "ValueOf" parameter, use a variable of the referenced cell. For example:

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim target As Double
    target = Range("B2")

    SolverReset
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$2", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="100"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$2", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$M$6", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=target, ByChange:="$G$2", _
      Engine:= 3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"
    SolverSolve

End Sub
```

Hope that addresses your issue.

Regards,
Sal