# VBA Solver Constraints Not Set Error (w/ no constraints specified)

Tags: vba, excel, solver, excel-2016

Firstly, I have tried researching the problem I have but the solutions I have found (for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352666/excel-solver-optimizing-using-changing-valueof-inputs), have not worked for me). I am trying to write a macro that uses the (normally) straightforward Solver functionality of solving for a value.

The code I have got to is as follows:

```
Sub SolverAEP()

    Dim GeneratedPower As Double
    GeneratedPower = Worksheets("AEP").Range("D57")

    SolverReset

    SolverOk SetCell:="$D$58", _
         MaxMinVal:=3, _
         ValueOf:=GeneratedPower, _
         ByChange:="$D$65" _
         , Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

    SolverSolve userFinish:=False    

End Sub
```

The error at present is that `Solver could not find a feasible solution. Sovler can not find a point for which all Constraints are satisified.`

What I have tried:

- Some online guidance says that the ValueOf needs to be a string - I tried the CStr approach to both `Range("D57")` and `Cells(57,"D").Value` and both came up with a Solver error.
- When I manually try to open Solver, it always opens up with a comma instead of a full stop, so I used a small script to replace all commas with a full stop, but that did not change anything (only tried this when I was dealing with a string as the `ValueOf`. [I am not sure why this actually happens, but I think there's some sort of a culture conflict as I'm using both a Continental and UK keyboard and localisation settings are fairly random.]
- Recording the macro doing the same manually in Solver gives me the below as the Solver code:

  ```
  Sub Macro2()
      SolverOk SetCell:="$D$58", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=21000#, ByChange:="$D$65" _
          , Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

      SolverOk SetCell:="$D$58", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=21000#, ByChange:="$D$65" _
          , Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

      SolverSolve
  End Sub
  ```
- The values I presently have could be rounded if necessary - as it seems when I stepped through my written macro that the decimal was still using a comma instead of a full stop. I tried rounding the value and putting that in there, but the same error came up.

Lastly, I should add that there is no problem in solving this manually with the Solver. The referenced cell D58 is a sum of other cells, the value of which depends on the value of D65.

Can anyone highlight what I am doing wrong please?

In case it matters, I'm using Excel 2016.

Comment: (a) Have you tried using `ValueOf:=Worksheets("AEP").Range("D57")` instead of `ValueOf:=GeneratedPower`? (Not sure why it would help, but it's worth a try.)  (b) Is "AEP" the active sheet when the macro is run?

Comment: I'll try that when I can. And, no, not the active sheet. Do you think that might make a difference?

Comment: Are cells $D$58 and $D$65 meant to be referring to the active sheet?  Or to the AEP sheet?  As it is currently set up, they will be referring to the active sheet.

Comment: @YowE3K: You are right; they are referring to the wrong sheet. I can't believe I missed something that obvious. Would you please post that as the answer?

Comment: @Yow3K: It would be appreciated if you could tell me why it seems I need to run the macro twice for the values to update after having put in a `Application.ScreenUpdating=False` bit of code when I use VBA to activate the other worksheet. If this doesn't make sense to you, no worries - you solved the main question I had. :) Cheers again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as if you are not activating the sheet on which your formulae exist, and therefore the Solve is doing its process on whatever the currently Active sheet is.

I recommend changing your code to:

```
Sub SolverAEP()

    With Worksheets("AEP")
        .Activate 

        SolverReset

        SolverOk SetCell:="$D$58", _
                 MaxMinVal:=3, _
                 ValueOf:=[$D$57], _
                 ByChange:="$D$65", _
                 Engine:=1, _
                 EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

        SolverSolve userFinish:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

The `Activate` will ensure that the correct sheet is selected when running the Solver.  (Much as I hate the use of `Activate`, `Select`, `Selection`, etc, this is one of those times it is required - the Solver will only work on the Active sheet.)

---

Re your comment about values not being updated until after you run the Solver a second time if you have an `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` statement included, I can't think of any reason other than the fairly obvious question "have you included a `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` statement as well?".

I tried running it with just the `=False` and running `SolverAEP` caused the screen to be updated once the macro ended.

However, if I wrote another subroutine such as the following:

```
Sub Test
    SolverAEP
    MsgBox "Finished first solve"
    SolverAEP
    MsgBox "Finished second solve"
End Sub
```

and ran it, then (with just a `=False` and no corresponding `=True`) the screen does not update until the `End Sub` of `Sub Test` is reached.  This is the expected behaviour of having stopped `ScreenUpdating`.

Comment: Thanks on both counts. I think you are right; I have a corresponding `=True` for the screenactivating, but I think it is not optimally placed. I will try your version of the worksheet activating and see how that works. The main problem has been solved though.